# Loop through primary keys and retrieve corresponding data?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8

I am trying to loop through an SQLite query and for every pk found I want to get the corresponding value of column `date`. Here is what I have so far. My dynamictextbox1 gets filled with code instead of the date.

```
    public void createEntry()
    {
        var dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "data.db");

        /*using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            db.CreateTable<LogEntry>();
            db.RunInTransaction(() =>
            {
                db.Insert(new LogEntry() { date = dateBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
                                           startTime = startTimeBox.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                                           endTime = endTimeBox.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                                           activity = activityBox.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                                           type = typeBox.SelectedItem.ToString()
                });
            });
        }*/

        //If the database is empty then don't set the listview itemssource to it otherwise you will get an error.
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            if (db.Table<LogEntry>().Count() > 0)
            {
                var query0 = db.Table<LogEntry>().Select(v => v.ID);
                var query1 = db.Table<LogEntry>().Select(v => v.date.ToString());
                var query2 = db.Table<LogEntry>().Select(v => v.startTime.ToString());
                var query3 = db.Table<LogEntry>().Select(v => v.endTime.ToString());
                var query4 = db.Table<LogEntry>().Select(v => v.activity.ToString());
                var query5 = db.Table<LogEntry>().Select(v => v.type.ToString());
                foreach (var item0 in query0)
                {

                    //var dateID = db.Table<LogEntry>().Where(v => v.ID = query0);

                    //Create the controls and populate them.
                    StackPanel dynamicStackPanel0 = new StackPanel();
                    dynamicStackPanel0.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

                    StackPanel dynamicStackPanel1 = new StackPanel();
                    StackPanel dynamicStackPanel2 = new StackPanel();
                    StackPanel dynamicStackPanel3 = new StackPanel();

                    TextBlock dynamicTextBlock1 = new TextBlock();
                    var dataID = db.Table<LogEntry>().Where( v => v.ID.Equals(item0)).Select(v => v.date);
                    dynamicTextBlock1.Text = dataID.ToString();

                    TextBlock dynamicTextBlock2 = new TextBlock();
                    foreach (var item2 in query2)
                    {
                        dynamicTextBlock2.Text = item2.ToString();
                    }

                    TextBlock dynamicTextBlock3 = new TextBlock();
                    foreach (var item3 in query3)
                    {
                        dynamicTextBlock3.Text = item3.ToString();
                    }

                    TextBlock dynamicTextBlock4 = new TextBlock();
                    foreach (var item4 in query4)
                    {
                        dynamicTextBlock4.Text = item4.ToString();
                    }

                    TextBlock dynamicTextBlock5 = new TextBlock();
                    foreach (var item5 in query5)
                    {
                        dynamicTextBlock5.Text = item5.ToString();
                    }

                    TextBlock dynamicTextBlock6 = new TextBlock();
                    dynamicTextBlock6.Text = "Rating 1";

                    TextBlock dynamicTextBlock7 = new TextBlock();
                    dynamicTextBlock7.Text = "Rating 2";

                    TextBlock dynamicTextBlock8 = new TextBlock();
                    dynamicTextBlock8.Text = "Rating 3";

                    //Create the entries.
                    dynamicStackPanel1.Children.Add(dynamicTextBlock1);
                    dynamicStackPanel1.Children.Add(dynamicTextBlock2);
                    dynamicStackPanel1.Children.Add(dynamicTextBlock3);

                    dynamicStackPanel2.Children.Add(dynamicTextBlock4);
                    dynamicStackPanel2.Children.Add(dynamicTextBlock5);

                    dynamicStackPanel3.Children.Add(dynamicTextBlock6);
                    dynamicStackPanel3.Children.Add(dynamicTextBlock7);
                    dynamicStackPanel3.Children.Add(dynamicTextBlock8);

                    dynamicStackPanel0.Children.Add(dynamicStackPanel1);
                    dynamicStackPanel0.Children.Add(dynamicStackPanel2);
                    dynamicStackPanel0.Children.Add(dynamicStackPanel3);

                    entryPanel.Items.Add(dynamicStackPanel0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select` gives you an enumerable of dates. You need `FirstOrDefault`.

```
var dataID = db.Table<LogEntry>().Where( v => v.ID == item0)
               .Select(v => v.date).FirstOrDefault();
dynamicTextBlock1.Text = dataID.ToString();
```

Comment: Im getting the error `no such function: equals` with that. Any suggestions

Comment: Changed it to "==". You didn't get the error before because you didn't really execute the query.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that. Thank you for your help.